# java GregorianCalendar adding hour strange behavior

Tags: java, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I have a problem with GregorianCalendar so if you please can help me out with it. First I'll give you my code:

```
private String changeClock(String day, String clock, int change) {
    String time="";
    DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
    try {
        Date d=df.parse(day+" "+clock);
        GregorianCalendar g=new GregorianCalendar();
        g.setTime(d);
        g.add(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, change);
        time=g.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR)+"-"
                +(g.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)+1)+"-"
                +g.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+" "
                +g.get(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"
                +g.get(GregorianCalendar.MINUTE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return time;
}
```

Let me explain what is happening. I have a GUI with + and - button. When someone press + it add one hour, or if - is pressed then take one hour.

Now example, time is 23:00 and I press +, it is everything ok and it jumps to 00:00 of the next day. Problems are on 12:00. If it is 12:00 and I press + it goes to 1:00 and that goes on and on. It doesn't move to the next day even after 2x12 hours or 21465x12 hours.
Moving backward is a little better if I can say so. When it is 00:00 and I press - it changes to yesterday 23:00 (also date changes). If I then press + it changes also one day forward (so to today in this case).

What have I done wrong or what more should I write to my code?

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: It seems like you are not showing us the real code you are trying to run (judging by `day` vs. `date`).   Maybe you could extract a self-contained example without needing any GUI, but a few lines - first to create a `Calendar` instance, then to call a `add()` operation and then to check the expected result.

Comment: This isn't related to your problem, but there's no need to manually build the String you return.  You can simply re-use your SimpleDateFormat object like this:  `return df.format(g);`.  [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) can work both ways: parsing **AND** formatting.

Comment: Grzegorz Oledzki I fixed that date-day issue. I had this in another language that you probably don't understand so I just changed to english quick.   jahroy, I know this ;) it's just example as I'm also doing some other things like learning my son about programming.

Comment: Try specifying 24-hour format by using `H` (capital H) in stead of `h` (lowercase h) when you create your [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your date format is wrong...

You're using `hh`, which is a representation of the *"Hour in am/pm (1-12)"*, so a time of 1pm is been converted to 1am instead.

You should be using `HH` which is a a representation of the *"Hour in day (0-23)"*.

Either that, or you need supply a date/time format with the am/pm marker...

Using either `DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");` or `DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a");`

Instead of relying on `String` date/time values, you should be passing in and back a `Date` object, leave the formatting for the display.

Comment: You and jahroy are right. Haven't made that mistake yet and I haven't even looking to this. Thanks guys. Till the next time.

Comment: +1 for recommending to pass a Date object rather than a String (and because this is a great answer)...

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse( 
    "2016-01-02 12:34:56".replace( " " , "T" ) 
)
```

## Using java.time

The [Answer by MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14269122/642706) is correct: Wrong code used in formatting pattern. But there is an even easier and better approach.

You are using troublesome old date-time classes now supplanted by the java.time classes.

Your input format in almost in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. Just replace the SPACE in middle with a `T`.

```
String input = "2016-01-02 12:34:56".replace( " " , "T" );
```

The java.time classe use ISO 8601 formats by default. So need to specify a formatting pattern at all, so no formatting codes to get wrong.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input );
```

We parse as a [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) because the input lacks information about offset-from-UTC or time zone. If this value was meant for UTC, apply an offset to get an [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

If meant for some time zone, transform into a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z );
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.